# How to prevent duplicate URLs in google sheet?

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Is it possible to prevent duplicate URLs in google sheet like the following:

User enters URL: https://superuser.com/questions/ in a row of column C.
If user wants to enter any subdomain or other URLs from superuser.com in other rows of column C, a warning is shown to user.
For example this URL should be flagged as duplicate: https://superuser.com/